# General use of initializers in SpriteKit game for creating spritenodes in Swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

The way we create sprite nodes that are loaded to the scene is the following:

```
var createNode: SKNode!

In viewDidLoad:
createNode = createNode1
addChild(createNode)
```

Then further along the line we have a method that creates this node such as:

```
func createNode1 () -> SKNode {
    // load and create node here 
{
```

Let's say we create this same node using init() method or initializer rather then what we did above in method `createNode1`. What difference would it make. The purpose of my use would be to use this same node throughout my app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might as well help you with this one too.

The main difference is that if you just create the function

```
 createNode1(...) -> SKNode {....
```

than all you can do is whats in that method, as in create the node.

```
  let node1 = createNode1()
  addChild(node1)
```

On the other hand if you would use a subclass you can create methods/properties specific for that node which you than can easily call in your scenes where you created the node.

e.g

```
 class Node: SKSpriteNode {

     var testBool = false

    init(....) {
    // node set up code

    }


 func test1() {
     // some code relevant to the node
 }

 func test2() {
   // some code relevant to the node
  } 
}
```

Now in your gameScene where you created the node you can call those methods or properties

```
 class GameScene: SKScene {

     var node1: Node!
     var node2: Node!

     didMoveToView........ {

     node1 = Node(...)
     addChild(node1)

     node2 = Node(...)
     addChild(node2)

     node1.test1()
     node1.test2()
     node1.testBool = true

     // you notice that I am only calling the methods for node 1, which means that node2 test func are not called yet and testBool is still false.

     // see the flexibility in this?
     // Main uses for this could be methods/properties for things such as animations, health,  etc
 }
```

If you didnt subclass than those methods/properties would have to be somewhere in your GameScene where they probably shouldnt really be because they are specific to that node and not the scene. You also couldn't add multiple nodes and than use the node1, or node2 etc instances to access the methods/properties to a specific node.

So in summary if you just need to render the nodes and nothing else than you can probably just keep that function.

However if you have specific methods that are relevant for that character, and I am sure you do, than you should subclass because it makes your code clearer in its intent and just cleaner in general.

Is this answering your question?

Comment: Perfectly explained, yes it helps, again, super explanation. Thank you.

Comment: My pleasure. Dont hesitate to ask further questions, thats what stack overflow is for as long as you post some code of what you are trying. Happy coding.

Comment: My friend. Since you are familiar with my current process where I use baseScene to create my 10 nodes and subclassing other 30 classes with this baseScene. If I come to one subclass that does not need node1 but needs other nine nodes, can I just use 'node1.removeFromParent'? I tried it and it works but however I would like to ensure this is the right approach to avoid use of this node in scene where this node is not needed. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah of course. You seem afraid to break stuff, dont be, just try it out.

Comment: I guess I am. I implemented it and it works perfect. How can we chat on this site? I'm new here. If you know send me a message and we can chat. Later.

Comment: Yeah there is this chat thing but I don't really use it so I'm not sure how to set it up. If you do invite me and we chat

Answer (score 0):

Let's say I create the following SKNode extension in Swift in a single swift class (i.e. NodeExtensions.swift).

```
extension SKNode {
  var x: CGFloat {
    get {
          return position.x 
    }
    set {
          position.x = newValue
    }
  }

  var y: CGFloat {
    get {
          return position.y 
    }
    set {
          position.y = newValue
    }
  }
}
```

Then in my GameScene : SKScene I create a function to draw a simple line from one point to another as following. Note I have already created sprite node `nodeA1` and `nodeA2` properties in this GameScene class and added these two nodes to the scene in viewDidLoad with specified positions using `CGRectGetMidX` and `CGRectGetMidY`.

```
// I first declare these globally in the class
let pathToDraw1 = CGPathCreateMutable()
let myLine1 = SKShapeNode()


// Then I create function below that uses pathToDraw1 and myLine1.
// Draw line from Node 1 to Node 2

func drawLine1to2() {
// Removes drawn line by enumerating the node with the name "line1"
enumerateChildNodesWithName("line1", usingBlock: {node, stop in node.removeFromParent()})

// Enumerate over this node
nodeA2.enumerateChildNodesWithName("A2_Broj", usingBlock: {node, stop in

    self.myLine1.name = "line1"

    CGPathMoveToPoint(self.pathToDraw1, nil, nodeA1.x, nodeA1.y) // From node
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(self.pathToDraw1, nil, nodeA2.x, nodeA2.y) // To node

    self.myLine1.path = self.pathToDraw1
    self.myLine1.strokeColor = SKColor.orangeColor()
    self.myLine1.zPosition = 2.0
    self.myLine1.lineWidth = 25

    self.addChild(self.myLine1)
})
}
```

Note the following lines using the x and y locations from the SKNode extension.

```
    CGPathMoveToPoint(self.pathToDraw1, nil, nodeA1.x, nodeA1.y) // From node
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(self.pathToDraw1, nil, nodeA2.x, nodeA2.y) // To node
```

By using this SKNode extension, I am able to use a single function to draw lines from one point to another using `CGPathMoveToPoint` and `CGPathAddLineToPoint` as shown above for any device (iPads and/or iPhones).

In summary!

1. Create SKNode extension.
2. Create and add to the scene two nodes (i.e. for this line draw example).
3. When using extension, specify in your functions/methods where each node is used as show in example above.

Note I am using line drawing just an example, but this same approach can be used within your own app design. The idea here is to use extension and have only one function/method obtain node locations that would work on any device.

Is this still the right way of implementing extensions to be used throughout out our apps? Thanks!